# If else statement Jquery help simple

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble making my else statement work. I want to change the background color from red to blue if the background color is red, if the background color is blue I want to change it to red. I cannot see why the code below is not working, can anybody help?

```js
        $(".box").css({
          "background-color": "red"
        });
        $(".box").click(function() {
          if ($(".box").css({
            "background-color": "red"
          })) {
            $(".box").css({
              "background-color": "blue"
            });
          } else {
            $(".box").css({
              "background-color": "red"
            });
          }
        });
```

```css
.box {

  height: 100px;

  width: 100px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>

    <div class="box"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `if` condition, the `.css()` method which when used in setter format returns the jQuery object which is alsways truthy that is why the else part is not executed.

If you want to compare the `background-color` then you need to use the `getter` version of `.css()` like `if($(".box").css('background-color') == 'red')`, but the value of color properties returned by the browser will depend on the browser(Some browser may return the `rgb` value of the hexa value) so comparing it may not always work.

One easy solution here is to use css classes to style the elements and toggle them use `toggleClass()`, in the below snippet we assigns the background color `red` to the `box` class, then the `clicked` class overrides the color to `blue` then we uses `toggleClass` to add/remove the class on click of the element.

```js
$(".box").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.box.clicked {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just check the value of css property `background-color`

```
var color =  $(".box").css( "background-color" );
```

here is the complete code

```js
        $(".box").css({
          "background-color": "red"
        });
        $(".box").click(function() {
          var color =  $(".box").css( "background-color" );
          if ( color == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" ) {
            $(".box").css({ "background-color": "blue" });
          } else {
            $(".box").css({ "background-color": "red" });
          }
        });
```

```css
.box {

  height: 100px;

  width: 100px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>

    <div class="box"></div>

</body>

</html>
```